# Generating an href value and route pattern from a common string

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

In [mvc-movie-giraffe](https://github.com/dharmatech/mvc-movie-giraffe) I have a [line](https://github.com/dharmatech/mvc-movie-giraffe/blob/718aca2f1c369619e88d73d9965687024db0faad/Program.fs#L247) like this in a view to generate a link to an edit page:

```ml
a [ _href ("/Movies/Edit/"    + (string elt.Id)) ] [ encodedText "Edit" ]
```

Then where I setup the routes, I [have the following](https://github.com/dharmatech/mvc-movie-giraffe/blob/718aca2f1c369619e88d73d9965687024db0faad/Program.fs#L626):

```ml
routef "/Movies/Edit/%i"    edit_handler
```

It would be nice to factor out that string `"/Movies/Edit/"`.

So I added it to a `Urls` module along with some others:

```ml
module Urls =

    let movies = "/Movies"
    let movies_create = "/Movies/Create"
    let movies_edit = "/Movies/Edit/%i"
```

For the `href` value:

```ml
a [ _href ("/Movies/Edit/"    + (string elt.Id)) ] [ encodedText "Edit" ]
```

we can do this instead:

```ml
a [ _href (sprintf (Printf.StringFormat<int->string>(Urls.movies_edit)) elt.Id) ] [ encodedText "Edit" ]
```

and for the route case:

```ml
routef "/Movies/Edit/%i"    edit_handler
```

we can do this:

```ml
routef (PrintfFormat<obj, obj, obj, obj, int>(Urls.movies_edit))    edit_handler
```

And this does appear to work!

My question is, is there a better way? Perhaps something more concise? The above is a bit syntax heavy. Or is there already some established best practice around this?

I looked through the [Giraffe samples](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/samples) and didn't notice anything like this technique being used.

## Update - Approach #2

Here's one approach. Basically, factor out those longer expressions as well:

```ml
module Urls =

    let movies = "/Movies"
    let movies_create = "/Movies/Create"

    let movies_edit = "/Movies/Edit/%i"
    let movies_edit_href = sprintf (Printf.StringFormat<int->string>(movies_edit))
    let movies_edit_route = PrintfFormat<obj, obj, obj, obj, int>(movies_edit)
```

And then reference them in views:

```
a [ _href (Urls.movies_edit_href elt.Id) ] [ encodedText "Edit" ]
```

and when setting up routes:

```
routef Urls.movies_edit_route edit_handler
```

## Update - approach #3

With approach #2, I ended up with this:

```
module Urls =

    let movies = "/Movies"

    let movies_create = "/Movies/Create"
    
    let movies_edit = "/Movies/Edit/%i"
    let movies_edit_href = sprintf (Printf.StringFormat<int->string>(movies_edit))
    let movies_edit_route = PrintfFormat<obj, obj, obj, obj, int>(movies_edit)

    let movies_details = "/Movies/Details/%i"
    let movies_details_href = sprintf (Printf.StringFormat<int->string>(movies_details))
    let movies_details_route = PrintfFormat<obj, obj, obj, obj, int>   (movies_details)

    let movies_delete = "/Movies/Details/%i"
    let movies_delete_href = sprintf (Printf.StringFormat<int->string>(movies_delete))
    let movies_delete_route = PrintfFormat<obj, obj, obj, obj, int>   (movies_delete)
```

There's some repetition there so I defined these extensions:

```
type String with
    member this.route = PrintfFormat<obj, obj, obj, obj, int>(this)
    member this.href = sprintf (Printf.StringFormat<int->string>(this))
```

Now, the `Urls` module is just:

```
module Urls =

    let movies         = "/Movies"
    let movies_create  = "/Movies/Create"
    let movies_edit    = "/Movies/Edit/%i"
    let movies_details = "/Movies/Details/%i"
    let movies_delete  = "/Movies/Details/%i"
```

And then to get the `href` string for `movies_edit`:

```
a [ _href (Urls.movies_edit.href elt.Id) ] [ encodedText "Edit" ]
```

And similar for the route:

```
routef Urls.movies_edit.route edit_handler
```

Answer (score 3):

I definitely do this at work to share url route templating.

```ml
type Route<'t> = PrintfFormat<obj, obj, obj, obj, 't>
let Details = Route<Guid> ("/Details/%O")
```

and then reference this in my route handlers as well as in my views to generate routes. There are a few caveats though:

- for values (like let bindings), you can't leave the generic parameters of the `PrintfFormat` type 'open'. So they get unified to `obj`, which is what you're seeing.
- if you *need* to keep the generic parameters open for some reason, the workaround is to convert the value to an `inline` function with a unit parameter, then invoke that function at each callsite:

```ml
let inline Details () = PrintfFormat<_,_,_,_,Guid> "/Details/%O"
```

this gets past the 'value restriction' that many ML-family languages have. You can look up that term for literature on why the generic parameters have to remain open on a value-binding.

Comment: Fancy seeing you here! :-)

Thanks sharing this!

Comment: I see how the above can be used for route handlers. In my case, given something like the above, I can do this:

`routef Details details_handler`.

However, you said that you reference the above in your views to generate routes. That part I'm not clear on. Can you give an example? Say generating a route for an `a` tag or a `form` `action` attribute?

Comment: exactly that. when generating a route to the details for a specific item, you can run `sprintf Details model.Id` to get the value for the href in the `a`, for example.

Comment: On my system, if I have the following: `let Details = Route<int> ("/Movies/Details/%i")` then the this `sprintf Details elt.Id` results in `The type 'PrintfFormat<obj,obj,obj,obj,int>' is not compatible with the type 'Printf.StringFormat<('a -> string)>'`.